# What is $a$ referring to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I don't understand the question and what it is asking for even after looking at the answer(which is in the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDPsv.png)). Does *a* represent the amplitude? Also why was the denominator equated to $0$ in the answer?

> A function is defined by the equation $ y= \frac{\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$
> for $0\leq x \leq 2\pi$ where $x\not=a$. State the exact values of
> *a*.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio That is a OP typo. Please consider checking the pictured

Comment: If you fix as Sassatelli says, question is only asking for the real number $a$ at which the formula is not defined. [Though to me the question is worded badly]. Find the value of $a$ making the denominator zero.

Comment: Poorly worded, but the question is basically asking at what value(s) the function $x\mapsto\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is asking you to find the values of $a$ where the function is not defined. For example if the question was a function $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\neq a$ then the answer would be $a=0$ because $f(x)$ is not defined there, in other words $a$ is not a part of the domain of the function. The answer is $a=0$ and $a=2\pi$ because that is where $1-\cos x=0$ and hence $f(x)$ cannot be defined.